# How can I make the URL of my Next.js application not change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, next.js

I have been asked that the Next.js project we are currently developing remains with the static URL, regardless of navigation between pages. The client has requested this, and we must do it. Could you give me some ideas on how to implement it?

The same url across the navigation

Comment: This makes no sense at all and is against web principles. Ask your "client" for the reason.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using iframes. But that would add an unnecessary layer of complexity, so yes, ask for the reason and if they're willing to pay for that extra work.

Comment: It is totally possible. But you need to have a global state and render the content based on it. I image a switch statement checking the state value and rendering the content.

Comment: Doing this hurts usability.  Users won't be able to bookmark or link to the content they want.  It also will hurt SEO.  Search engines won't index anything but the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was about ideas, as I mentioned in a comment, the only thing I can think of is using iframes. But that would add an unnecessary layer of complexity, so yes, ask for the reason and if they're willing to pay for that extra work.

Comment: The thing is, my project manager mentioned that we should consider the option of doing it that way, but it involves more extra work. Are there any additional drawbacks that could arise from doing it this way?

Comment: That would be one that you can better google, because there are many articles and questions online that describe possible drawbacks.

Comment: This comment on your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064210/how-can-i-make-the-url-of-my-next-js-application-not-change/78064396?noredirect=1#comment137622058_78064210 actually mentions another option, which, thinking about it now, would make more sense.